# Putting two different variables from two different models at the same line in Django templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I need to get a Django Template like

"First Blog Heading" - ("number of Comments of first blog")

"Second Blog Heading"- ("number of Comments of second blog")

What's the easiest way to do this?
I tried to create a context in my views.py having both from Blog model and Comment model since variables belong to different models. And then I needed to put both variables into for loop in my html but it turn out a nested loop. So I didn’t  get the look I want.

I open to every kind of solution not from back-end but also front-end
Thank you

I updated my question and I added my models and views

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    def __str__(self):
        self.name
    
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    text = models.CharField(max_length= 5000)
    
     def __str__(self):
        self.name
    
class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text_comment = models.CharField(max_length=2000)



def index(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.all
    comments = Blog.objects.annotate(number=Count('comments'))
    context = {'blog':blogs, 'comments':comments}
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```

TEMPLATE (Which does not work)

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
{% for comment in comments %}
{{ blog.heading }} {{ comment.number }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: is there a relation between blogs and comments? can you share your models.py?

Answer (score 0):

There is hard to imagine what data you have.

For example finally you get two dictionaries `blogs` and `comments` before view's return statement.
After that you need to join two dictionaries by foreign key.
`comment["blog_id"]` and `blog["id"]` in my example.

For example:

```py
blogs = [
 {"name": "A", "id": 1, "text": "someblogA"},
 {"name": "B", "id": 2, "text": "someblogB"},
 {"name": "C", "id": 3, "text": "someblogC"},
 {"name": "D", "id": 4, "text": "someblogD"},
]

comments = [
 {"text": "commentA", "id": 11, "blog_id": 1},
 {"text": "commentB", "id": 12, "blog_id": 2},
 {"text": "commentC", "id": 13, "blog_id": 2},
 {"text": "commentD", "id": 14, "blog_id": 3},
]

for blog in blogs:
  blog['num_of_comments'] = 0
  for comment in comments:
    if comment["blog_id"] == blog["id"]:
      blog['num_of_comments'] += 1
```

After that you can use this syntax:

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
  {{blog.name }} {{blog.num_of_comments }}
{% endfor %}
```

But in my opinion the better way will be create Serializer and join blogs and comments inside it.
[Serializer relations with django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already annotated the count of comments for each blog, you can reach "number" from Blog queryset:

```
# views.py
def index(request):
    blog_with_comments = Blog.objects.annotate(number=Count('comments'))
    context = {'blog_with_comments': blog_with_comments}
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)

#template
{% for blog in blog_with_comments %}
   {{ blog.heading }} {{ blog.number }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you're welcome. Can you resolve the question if the answer is enough?